# Siddhi javascript error could not initialize class io.siddhi.extension.script.js.EvalJavaScript

Tags: javascript, siddhi

When I try to use a javascript function I get this error: "could not initialize class io.siddhi.extension.script.js.EvalJavaScript"

I see in the lib folder that the siddhi-script-js-5.0.3.jar is there, both in the runner and the tooling, do I need to install any more extension?

I think there is a BUG in Siddhi with the javascrpt plugin.

I add the Siddhi official example and there is an error, you can notice in the third image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Alexander as soon as I have the solution I will let you know, I don't have yet

Comment: Same issue . Any solution?

Comment: The problem is with Siddhi Docker. When you use Siddhi in a Docker and you call a JavaScript function, then you get that error, but if you use Siddhi installed in your system but not using Docker, it doesn't have that bug.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is an official bug from Siddhi-Docker, as the base JDK image used for the dockerization is a slim version, which doesn't have the NashornScript libraries for JS compilation.

The siddhi-runner works on using a non-slim version of base JDK image. I have verified it locally and it works well. My pull request is pending for review.

https://github.com/siddhi-io/docker-siddhi/pull/33

Comment: Lokkesh when they have accepted your pull request let us know please